# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) - Styling the Relationship Field - CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I've used ACF Pro to enable selection of one post type from another, along with some other custom fields. The main selection uses a Relationship field type, but there seems to be no control over how this appears and it's pretty clunky.

Is there a way of implementing a more traditional WordPress check box as seen in the meta boxes, rather than the ACF style selection box?

The ACF one also allows multiple selections in each row, I need it to be single selection per row.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using the relationship field type? It might be worth using a different type of field?

Comment: It needs to pull in a list from another post type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a dropdown list of a specific custom post types set your field type to **Post Object** and then set your **Filter by Post Type**  to the custom post type you want displayed in that list.